# Getting Entity object in correct collation from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, collation

We have a SQL Server database with collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` / `Windows-1252`. In this database, rows are saved with some windows Baltic symbols (for example, `Šilutė`, `Šiauliai`, `Čiobiškis`).

I am using Entity Framework to get objects from this database, but objects string symbols don't show correctly:

`Šilutė, Šiauliai, Čiobiškis` show up as `Ðilutė, Ðiauliai, ðiobiÐkis`

Yes, in C# code I can to encode every string like this:

```
private String ChangeEncoding(String text)
{
     Encoding w1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
     Encoding w1257 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1257");
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
     {
          return text;
     }
     return w1257.GetString(w1252.GetBytes(text));
}
```

but I think that encode every string property in class object is not very clever idea.

Maybe there is a simplest way to get entity objects in correct collation?

Comment: What **datatype** does your column in the database have??

Comment: Varchar(50-255) for string properties.

Comment: Have you tried using `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`? This is a Unicode string type, which should support all special characters, regardless of the collation of the database

Comment: I doesn't have enough rights to change db/table design. Only for reading.